# Google Maps API Markers show randomly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
function geocode(wordOne, wordTwo) {
  axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
    params: {
      address:wordOne + ' ' + wordTwo,
      key:'BLAH'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log("geocode success");
    //get long and lat JSON data and append locations array
    var latandlong = response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
    locations.push(latandlong);
    console.log(locations);

  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log("geocode error");
  });
}

function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
  });

  var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
    });
  });

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
      {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
```

For some reason, although console.log(locations) shows the array is being correctly appended to, every time i refresh the page, only a handful of random markers from the array show. The markers change every time the page refreshes. I am so confused. You can view it yourself at redditglobe.me

Answer (score 1):

You're calling initMap immediately, and then trying to use the `locations` array to add your markers.

However `locations` is only populated after each call to the `axios.get` request in the `geocode` function completes.

And each call to that `geocode` function only happens after you've made an ajax request for your `posts_replied_to.txt` file.  So that probably happens after the `initMap` function.

You should move the code adding the markers into the `then` block.  Or perhaps at the end of the `success` handler for your `$.ajax()` request.